# How To Setup a Two Way Binding To a Valid Reference but Empty/ New Object

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

How does one properly setup the binding to a class object where all properties are valid but empty?

---

**Works**...If the component is declared as such:

```
export class BioComponent implements OnInit {

 bio : Bio  = { id : 1, FirstName : "", LastName : ""};

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

In the view as the user edits, the following bindings work and the third line below shows what the user has typed in.

```
<td><input [(ngModel)]="bio.FirstName" placeholder="Your first name"></td>
<td><input [(ngModel)]="bio.LastName" placeholder="Your last name"></td>
<td>{{bio.FirstName + ' ' + bio.LastName}}</td>
```

---

**Fails**

If `bio : Bio  = new Bio();` is set, then the third item shows `undefined undefined` until the user types in something to each of the inputs.

---

**To Sum Up** I don't want to have to have things like `FirstName : "",` property declarations for each property. How does one new up a new object in Angular/TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define and initialize the data members in the constructor, with default values:

```
export class Bio {

  constructor(
    public id: number = 0, 
    public firstName: string = '', 
    public lastName: string = '') {
  }
}
```

You can create `Bio` objects as follows:

```
bio1 = new Bio();
bio2 = new Bio(1);
bio3 = new Bio(2, 'Robert');
bio4 = new Bio(3, 'Jane', 'Smith');
```

You can see the code at work in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l9hadb).

Answer (score 1):

You can in your `Bio` class setup a default value.

```
export class Bio {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;

  constructor(id: number = 0, first: string = '', last: string = '') {
      this.id = id;
      this.firstName = first;
      this.lastName = last;
  }
}
```

then in your component

`bio: Bio = new Bio();` will be initialized with defaults.

Comment: You can declare the members directly in the constructor.

Comment: That wouldn't default the values though?

Comment: No, you can set the default values.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I'm curious do tell :D